# Delete Activex checkboxes in selection

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to write a macro that would delete all activex checkboxes within selected range. I wrote this code, but it keeps returning "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Please help.

```
Dim cbx As OLEObject
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = selection
For Each cbx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If Not Intersect(rng, cbx.Object.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then cbx.Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If Not Intersect(rng, cbx.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then cbx.Delete
```

Comment: Works great . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all ActiveX Checkboxes within a selection:

```
Sub DeleteActiveXCheckboxes()

Dim Shape As Shape

For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Shape.Type = 12 Then
        If Not Intersect(Shape.TopLeftCell, Selection) Is Nothing Then
            Shape.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next Shape

End Sub
```